# Automating IKEv2 VPN Connection & Enabling Killswitch on macOS Boot

Tags: macos, terminal, automation, applescript, vpn

Hey StackOverflow community!

I've been grappling with a challenge of automatically connecting to my IKEv2 VPN on macOS boot and concurrently triggering the command `sudo killswitch -e` to block all traffic when the VPN isn't active.

I've already taken a dive into a couple of methods centered around networksetup, but hit a roadblock. When I punch in the command:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

It rolls out a list of all my network services, BUT it curiously omits my IKEv2 connections. I've flirted with the idea of using LaunchAgents for the auto-boot execution, but without the capability to identify and manipulate a specific IKEv2 connection, it's been a no-go.

I've also dabbled with commands to initiate the VPN connection, such as `sudo networksetup -connectpppoeservice "My VPN Name"`, but to no avail.

I'm keen to unearth if there are alternative avenues to harness IKEv2 connections via the macOS terminal or any other clever hacks around this conundrum.

Much appreciated in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `scutil` (and `networksetup`) on MacOS doesn't work with IKEv2. Give a try to `vpnutil` (https://github.com/Timac/VPNStatus):

```
vpnutil start "My VPN Name"
```

More info can be found here: https://blog.timac.org/2018/0719-vpnstatus/.